# Characteristic polynomial of a tree

Tags: graph-theory, determinant, trees, spectral-graph-theory

I'm trying to understand the article: [László Lovász, Jozsef Pelikan, *On the Eigenvalues of Trees*, Periodica Mathematica Hungarica, March 1973](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243037233_On_the_Eigenvalue_of_Trees).
I'm not sure I fully understand the proof of Lemma 1: if $e$ is an edge of a forest $G$, $$f_G(\lambda)=f_{G-e}(\lambda)-f_{G-[e]}(\lambda)$$ where $f_G$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of $G$, $G-e$ is $G$ with edge $e$ removed, and $G-[e]$ is $G$ with $e$ removed and its endpoints. I've tried to write the adjacency matrix and to expand the determinant but I still don't understand it.

Comment: For now, let me only say two things: (1) This holds more generally when $G$ is any graph and $e$ is a bridge (i.e., an edge whose removal would increase the number of connected components of $G$).

Comment: (2) Lovász and Pelikan suggest to expand the determinant by its first $k$ column; I don't think this is the best way. Instead, what I would do is the following: The matrix $\lambda I - A_G$ has the (block) form $\begin{pmatrix} U & P \\ Q & V \end{pmatrix}$, where $U$ and $V$ are two square matrices, and where $P$ and $Q$ are two "almost-zero" matrices. More precisely, all entries of $P$ are $0$ except for a $-1$ in its bottom-left corner, and all entries of $Q$ are $0$ except for a $-1$ in its top-right corner. Moreover, ...

Comment: ... the matrix $\lambda I - A_{G - e}$ has the form $\begin{pmatrix} U & 0 \\ 0 & V \end{pmatrix}$ with the same $U$ and $V$. Finally, the matrix $\lambda I - A_{G - [e]}$ has the form $\begin{pmatrix} U' & 0 \\ 0 & V' \end{pmatrix}$, where $U'$ and $V'$ are appropriate submatrices of $U$ and $V$. Now, you need to prove that $\det\left(\lambda I - A_G\right) = \det\left(\lambda I - A_{G - e}\right) - \det\left(\lambda I - A_{G - [e]}\right)$. Write the left hand side as a sum over all permutations $\sigma$ of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$. Show ...

Comment: ... that the $\sigma$s that send $1,2,\ldots,k$ to some reordering of $1,2,\ldots,k$ make up $\det\left(\lambda I - A_{G - e}\right)$, whereas the $\sigma$s that send $k$ and $k+1$ to $k+1$ and $k$ (in this order) make up $- \det\left(\lambda I - A_{G - [e]}\right)$, and all the remaining $\sigma$s just give vanishing addends.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it a lot better now.